# Inverse Resize for a jquery UI Resizable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-resizable

I'm creating a way for the user to resize divs , and I'm using Jquery's UI library which works fine. However, say I wish to invert the position of the content (usually some kind of image), horizontally or vertically, I cannot seem to do it. the resizable div wrapping the image does not resize beyond the top and left position ? Any idea how I could do it using jquery resizable.

EDIT: This is the jsfiddle (in the comment below)  where I have put the minHeight as -100 but when resizing the height does not go beyond 0. I need it to be negative as well.

Comment: Could you provide sample replicating your issue? In fact, you ***must*** provide it in question;)

Comment: It's a normal resizable with handles on all sides. but if i try to resize such that it's width or height is negative (at which point I expect the div to invert.), it doesn't let me do it. I'll try to create a sample, but it seems pointless creating a resizable div working the way it normally does, because I cent get the div to resize, the way I want it for this particular condition.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/e02vbwxc/4/

Comment: Can anyone here help?